# where is the style code for the ui time picker?

Tags: css, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am working with html5 for a web project , I want to add ui-time picker(from the ui.bootstrap library https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.2.5/ ) to my page , the problem  is that I am already using bootstrap version. there fore if I use the version for the time picker other elements get bad style , and if I use the previous version the time Picker get bad style.
i tried mixing the two version , I am not sure i did that the right way.

Comment: it is worthy to notice that i found out what are the class used in the ui directive but i could not find them in neither of the version (uib-increment , hours , minutes ... )

Comment: Mostafa Gazar , the link you provided talks about android styling , I am using html5 and css , I am not sure if there is any difference between them , but I am sure i do not have the attribute timePickerMode ,